# wkhtmltoimage - trying to get thumbail from site hosted in the same ip

Tags: webpage-screenshot, wkhtmltoimage

I'm trying to get site thumbnails using wkhtmltoimage

It seems to be working except from sites that are being hosted in the same ip

This is what i get from shell when requesting a thumbnail from another site hosted to the same server:

```
Loading page (1/2)
QHttpNetworkConnectionChannel::_q_receiveReply() called without QHttpNetworkReply, 0 bytes on socket.
Rendering (2/2)
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used   ] 25%
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
QPainter::translate: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
QPainter::setWorldTransform: Painter not active
QPainter::setOpacity: Painter not active
QPainter::setFont: Painter not active
Segmentation fault
```

Is there a way to solve this issue or i have to order a second ip for my server?

Comment: Are you sure that this is a php problem? What have you tried so far to solve this problem?